# Faulty iterations

Tags: replication, anylogic

I have created an experiment with a fixed number of replications. The goal is that after each replication the throughput, which I store via a variable and dataset in the model, is given to me. If I run a single replication, I get plausible values. However, if the experiment runs, say, 3 replications, replication 2 and 3 are run much too fast and in my data the throughputs/values of the agents are no longer plausible. There are fewer agents in replication two and seemingly no agents at all in iteration three (see also picture from Excel output). This makes no sense to me, as with a fixed seed the same or at least similar results should appear from replication to replication in my eyes.

It sounds to me like the system is not really resetting between replications. A replication is finished by a getEngine().finish() in the model.

Does anyone here have an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

I already tried different stoping rules and different experiment types. Nevertheless, only the first replication seems to deliver true values.

[image]

Comment: 2 things: Are you sure you set it to fixed seed? And try running the experiment with sequential runs (turn of parallel runs in the experiment advanced properties). If the latter fixes it, you have some data spill over between runs

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, the seed is fixed and the changes in the settings do not change the result. What I noticed is when I use significantly less agents it works perfectly. From a certain rate of agents, it doesn't work anymore and I don't get any values in the third replication at the latest.

Comment: run it as a Simulation experiment with few and many agents and investigate :)

Comment: FYI: Solved the problem. Collections and variables are not allowed to be static. :)
https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/optimization.html under "Advanced".